# Highlight the maximum occurance within a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have created a pivot table with Column A and Column B. Column A has one to many relation with Column B.

I want to highlight the value in Column B which occurs many times in its scope with value in Column A. For example in the below table, I want 10 to be highlighted for ABC and 15 to be highlighted for XYZ scope.

```
COLA        COLB
ABC          10
ABC          10
ABC          15
XYZ          10
XYZ          15
XYZ          15
```

If there is a tie, any one value needs to be highlighted.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I highly recommend having your column A value in every row of column A.  So, assuming your data setup looks like this:

(updated image)

[image]

Then select cell B2 and create a new conditional format via formula.  The conditional format formula is (updated):

```
=AND(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A2,$B$2:$B2,$B2)=1,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$A2,$B$2:$B$7,$B2)=MAX(INDEX(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$A2,$B$2:$B$7,$B$2:$B$7),)))
```

And as you can see based on the above screenshot, it highlights the first `10` for value `ABC` and it highlights the first `15` for value `XYZ`

Adjust the conditional format formula ranges to suit your actual data.

**EDIT**: Updated answer based on comments and updated question from OP

Comment: Thanks for the nice formula but I think there seems to be an error. I just brings the maximum value i.e. 15 for XYZ. If you just replace B5 to 20, then 20 will be highlighted.

Comment: I think my question was little vague. I wanted to highlight the number that occurred the most. Not the highest in value. I have updated the example above.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. The formula seems to break if ABC has three different values. It highlights all the values if it couldn't find a maximum occurrence for a single value. Is there a way to use MODE? I'm quite new to excel so sorry if I'm being rudimentary. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I found another way to fix the gap in the formula.Thanks for this wonderful formula. I wouldn't have got this in a million years!! Thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to tweak this formula? I have 60,000 rows and excel crashes with the current formula. Thanks!!

Comment: @mani_nz In that case, instead of a conditional format formula you would be much better off with a pivot table.  The pivot will show the unique entries for your HeaderA, and then you can tell it to show the maximum values for your HeaderB.  It uses significantly less resources than formulas or VBA, and you can right-click on the pivot table and select Refresh to have it update when new data is added.  You can put the Pivot table on a separate worksheet if preferred.